# iOS Record game based on UIImageView animations

Tags: ios, uiimageview, recording

I have an iOS app with a game based on animated UIImageView.

I want to record the game play.

I found a [library](http://aroth.no-ip.org:82/wordpress/archives/673) that capture an UIImage on every drawRect and then make a video with all the UIImages.
The library not work for me because the video only take 5 frame per second.

Another alternative that I found is user [Everyplay](https://developers.everyplay.com/doc) library but only works with coco2d or unity.

Do I have any alternative way? I must migrate my game to coco2d?

I need the video of the gameplay to be shared on facebook.

Comment: Do you need a **video** of the gameplay? If so, could you please explain what you plan to do with it? Depending on what you need it for, there could be far better alternatives...

Comment: I need the video of the gameplay to be shared on facebook.

Comment: ok, so there are no _better_ _alternatives_, it seems (I was thinking about recording the moves of the session, but this can't clearly help you)... :)